# React -js Development server unable to complete the loading

Tags: reactjs

I was working on my React-js project and suddenly this happened.
When I run npm start everything compiles fine and the cli fires up the local server, but the server stays loading forever.[image]

[image]

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing node_modules ,upgrading node version and clearing the cache 
but nothing seems to work .I'm knida stuck for two days now . I'm trying to download a zip which contains the code but I'm getting invalid directory name error[image]

**Really need some help to move On **

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console? Open the dev tools and see if you can spot a problem there.

Comment: I'm unable to inspect